# Superscript characters in Prestashop 1.7 product name

Tags: html, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

One of the products in my website has a superscript character in the product name. Since Prestashop does not allow HTML tags inside product names, I need to find a way to display the superscript character correctly in the product page.

While searching around, I found somebody with a similar problem: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/543339-how-to-make-superscript-format-%C2%AE-symbol-in-category-name-and-product-name/. They seemed to resolve the issue by modifying a line of code in the product.tpl file of their theme:

```
 <h1 itemprop="name">{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'|replace:'character':'<sup>character</sup>'}</h1>
```

I tried this solution, but instead of replacing only the one character with its superscript version, the theme displays the entire string as plain text, including the sup tags. Cleared the cache, set to force recompile template files, nothing.

Clearly the "replace" command does work, but I can't figure out why the sup tags don't. Does anybody know a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I think it is because of `escape:'html':'UTF-8'` part. I guess if you remove it html won't be escaped in  `$product->name`.

Comment: Tried removing that, but nothing changed. The sup tags still show up in the product name.

Comment: What particular characters are you trying to display as superscript?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel It's a single number, specifically.

Comment: What if you use the unicode equivalent of the superscript digits instead? See https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/superscript-and-subscript-numbers/

Comment: @justin-ezequiel Thank you so much, using the unicode worked. I had tried using the HTML-code before but it also didn't work, looks like there's no way to display HTML in the title after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the unicode equivalent of the superscript digits instead.

See https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/superscript-and-subscript-numbers/